Automatic volume lowering during notifications
When I listen to the music with Deezer, Android briefly lowers music volume during any notification. Is it possible to hear notifications with no music lowering (audio ducking). I have Samsung Galaxy s23 ultra with the latest firmware. Sound assistant app didn't help.
Thanks in advance!
Existing answer does't help. I do not need DND mode.
